# How to remove // from URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to remove / from URL if they appear twice or thrice.
Like:

```
 www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search//2/Pool-Villa
```

should become

```
 www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search/2/Pool-Villa
```

and

www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search///Beach-Villa

should become

www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search/Beach-Villa

Comment: But first let us know why url is like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectMatch directive With Regex, so If an additional forword slash was added accidently to the url ,then you have a chance to make it optional or permanently delete it from the url.

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search//?/?/2/(.*)$ /mauritius_holiday_rentals/search/2/$1


 RedirectMatch 301 ^/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search//?/?/(.*)$ /mauritius_holiday_rentals/search/$1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/search///$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 trailing slashes?

Comment: There would not be more than three slashes but multiple slashes can be any where in URL.